# How to set a logging level per handler and per module using python's logging module

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'd like to set different logging levels per handler and logger in python. I'd like debug level logs for all loggers to be sent to their filehandlers, but be able to individually select the log level for each logger for what's printed to the console.

```py
import logging

loggerA = logging.getLogger('a')
fhA = logging.FileHandler(filename='a.log', mode='w')
fhA.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
loggerA.addHandler(fhA)

loggerB = logging.getLogger('b')
fhB = logging.FileHandler(filename='b.log', mode='w')
fhB.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
loggerB.addHandler(fhB)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('a').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('b').setLevel(logging.WARN)
loggerA.info("TEST a")
loggerB.info("TEST b")
```

I'd expect all logs to be sent to the files, but only show WARNING and above from 'b' in the console, and INFO and above from 'a' in the console. With the above code, 'b' doesn't have any logs in the file.

Comment: if you set logger's level to `logging.WARN`, it will not log anything below that level, i. e. `INFO` and `DEBUG`.also set logger's level with a logger object, example: `loggerA.setLevel(logging.INFO)`.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I set the appropriate logging levels everywhere so I get debug level in b's file handler, but warning level for b in the console, and info level for a in the console?

Comment: this will help you, [doc link](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow)

Comment: If you want `b` to log to a file AND print to the console, you will need 2 `Handler`s, with their desired levels, and then set the `logger`'s level as the minimum